# How do I make a HTTP GET request to a Kerberos protected site using Haskell

Tags: python, http, haskell, get, kerberos

Essentially I would like to do this ([Python](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos)) but in Haskell:

```
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth, OPTIONAL
kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL)
r = requests.get("http://example.org", auth=kerberos_auth)
```

I know [I can just do](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/):

```
import Network.Wreq
r <- get "http://httpbin.org/get"
```

But I been unable to find an example that supports kerberos negotiation